# Multiple Functions on Google Script

Tags: function, time, static, uppercase

Thanks in advance for your time here. I am self taught and new to coding, hence apologies if the question below is something an average programmer should already know.

Both functions when run individually work without issues.

```
    function onEdit(e) {

var sheetToWatch= 'Sheet1',
columnToWatch = "8,9", columnToStamp = 12; 

var edited_column = e.range.getColumn();

if (columnToWatch.indexOf(edited_column.toString()) === -1) {return;}

if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getName() !== sheetToWatch || !e.value) return;

if (edited_column === 8) {
columnToStamp = 12;
} else if (edited_column === 9) {
columnToStamp = 13;
}

e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
.setValue(new Date());

}
```

This is the first code. And works perfect. When I put data in 8 and 9 columns. Static time appear 12 and 13 columns.

Second code is;

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

This code helps me the uppercase whole document.

But 2 codes doesnt work same time.

Can u guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since both functions are called `onEdit()`, there is a name clash when you try to call the functions in Google Script, since they don't know which `onEdit()` to call (the one that capitalizes or the one that adds the time stamp?).

If you're running these functions manually, try renaming them.

If they're being triggered by the edit action and you can't modify the names, you can merge the bodies of the functions.

Say you have this originally:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    e.value.toUpperCase();
}
function onEdit(e) {
    e.setValue("hi");
}
```

You could combine them like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    e.setValue("hi");
    e.value.toUpperCase();
}
```